# Blazor WASM Eventhandler not triggering on razor component

Tags: c#, events, blazor

I have a Blazor WASM solution. In my solution server-side I have a API controller. I want that controller to trigger an Eventhandler on my client-side razor component.

I have a service client side, interface:

```
public event EventHandler UpdatePage;

public void TestMethodeMart()
{

}
```

Class:

```
public event EventHandler UpdatePage;

 public void TestMethodeMart()
 {
     UpdatePage?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
 }
```

I have registered the service both client side as server side:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITestMartInterface, TestMartInterface>();
```

I injected the service in my controller (server side)

```
private readonly ITestMartInterface _testMart;

public AtsMessageReceivedController(ITestMartInterface testMart)
{
    _testMart = testMart;
}
```

And via my GET methode I invoke my Event

```
[HttpGet]
 public async void Get()
 {
     _testMart.TestMethodeMart();
 }
```

In my razor I inject my service

```
@inject ITestMartInterface testMartInterface
```

In my razor I subscribe to my event in the OnInitialized

```
testMartInterface.UpdatePage += DoStuff;
```

And I want this methode to run when event is triggered:

```
public async void DoStuff(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code must run when event is triggered
}
```

The event fires when I access the GET methode, but my methode on razor component is not hit..

Comment: If I read this correctly you want an event raised in the API on your Server to trigger an event handler in the WASM client?  Not possible without setting up something like a SignalR session between the two.  They are tow totally separate applications.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis ok clear! Thats was indeed what i tried to achieve. Thank you for this comment! I will stop trying and use SignalR